# MySQL Idle for some time and then query timeout after 15 mins

Tags: php, python, mysql

I have noted that when mySQL/application(PHP/Python) is idle for some time and then someone logs into my system, even simple login query takes more than 15 mins and then connection timesout afte waiting for 15+ minutes.
The same query take millisec to return result.

Any idea on what could be the issue? I dont think it is my SQL issue. Could it be Application, VM, Infra issue?
 Below are current parameters for mySQL:

```
connect_timeout 10
delayed_insert_timeout  300
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout    120
innodb_rollback_on_timeout  OFF
interactive_timeout 28800
lock_wait_timeout   31536000
net_read_timeout    30
net_write_timeout   60
rpl_stop_slave_timeout  31536000
slave_net_timeout   3600
wait_timeout    28800
```

Comment: What infrastructure are you using currently for running mysql? I mean to know the configuration of the server running mysql

Comment: It is running on Linux VM.